# Wrong font in embedded Google Sheet

Tags: css, google-sheets

I'm embedding a Google Sheet on a website. I'm using Lekton as the font, but when shown in the iframe it's Arial. When checking the Google Chrome inspector it says font-family: 'docs-lekton'.

Changing the font via css doesn't seem to work - any ideas on how to get it to show Lekton correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `font-family` or other css properties inside `iframe`, if you don't have access to content in `iframe` (e.g. content in `iframe` is your other website, that you want to embed).
In your case, Google Sheets is Google content, including all css, that styles spreadsheets.

It works this way because content inside `iframe` isn't really part of your current page, that's why you call it **embedding**.